# dual basis, $\wedge$-product

Tags: multilinear-algebra

I have to following statement, which I want to proof. Unfortunatly I am not used to the dual space and know barely anything about it.

I want to proof what seems trivial. Namely:

Let $e_1,\dotso, e_k$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^k$ and let $\delta^1,\dotso,\delta^k$ be the dual basis of $\mathbb{R}^{k\ast}$, then is

$\delta^1\wedge\dotso\wedge\delta^k(e_1,\dotso, e_k)=1$ for every $k\geq 1$.

If I am informed right, then $\delta^i(e_j)=\begin{cases}1\quad,\text{for}\,\,j=i\\0\quad,\text{else}\end{cases}$ just by definition, of the dual basis.

The statement should follow easily by induction.
The start for k=1 is trivial by definition.
Since the $\wedge$-product is associative the inductive step should go like this:

$\delta^1\wedge\dotso\wedge\delta^{k+1}(e_1,\dotso,e_{k+1})=(\delta^1\wedge\dotso\wedge\delta^k)(e_1,\dotso, e_k)\wedge\delta^{k+1}(e_{k+1})=1\wedge\delta^{k+1}(e_{k+1})
\\=1\wedge 1=1$

Is this correct?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first equality holds, because the $\wedge$-product is associative. That is what I thought at least. For $r,s$ forms $\omega$ and $\eta$ it is $(\omega\wedge\eta)(v_1,\dotso, v_{r+s})=\frac{1}{r!s!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{r+s}}sgn(\sigma)\omega(v_{\sigma(1)},\dotso,v_{\sigma(r)})\eta(v_{\sigma(r+1)},\dotso, v_{\sigma(r+s)})$ Edit: The comment this comment is refering to, got deleted.